# HotSpot authorization through Social Likes

Tags: facebook, twitter, wifi, social-networking

I'm setting up a wifi network for a company, i want to create a wifi hotspot that requires the user to be a fan (facebook liker) or a follower (twitter) from the company social accounts, to be able tu use the wifi for free. if their not "followers" they would have to be redirected to follow or like our company social accounts to get access.

if they arent followers of any kind, THERE WILL BE NO ACCESS!!

also if they stop being followers once they have granted access the network should expulse them from the wifi

any ideas?, tutorials? or past experience will be highly apreciated

Comment: A sinister plan. I'm creating fake Facebook and Twitter accounts to get around your shenanigans already. ;-)

Comment: I removed the hotspot tag, as that refers to the HotSpot virtual machine which is the standard one used in the Oracle and OpenJDK Java runtime environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently deploying a similar solution in various areas in the United States, and throughout Europe, with great success.  We have included bluetooth marketing, and the ability to upload coupons to your custom Wi-Fi page and Fan Page News Feed.